# MySql left join update rows in table a even when there are no rows in table b

Tags: mysql, sql

What is the join to be used when updating rows in two tables, that will update rows in tablea, even when there are no rows in table b?

Here's what is failing me:

```
update
  items_mod a
  left join item_images b on a.itemHandle = b.imgHandle
set
  a.itemPubStatus = 0,
  a.itemStatusSet = 1,
  a.itemAdminMessage = 'Test',
  b.imgStatus = 1,
  b.imgPublished = 1 
where
  a.itemId = 2 
  and a.itemPubStatus = 2
  and a.itemPrePub = 1
  and b.imgStatus = 0
  and b.imgDeleted = 0;
```

There are rows in `item_images`, but none that fulfill the two conditions `b.imgStatus = 0 and b.imgDeleted = 0`

How can the sql be coded so that the sql will update `item_mod` even when there's nothing to update in `item_images`?

Comment: the problem is in where clause. you are writing b.imgstatus and b.imgDeleted even if they are null. comment them and try if i identified the problem correctly. then i will write the answer on how it can be done

Answer (score 1):

place

```
and b.imgStatus = 0
  and b.imgDeleted = 0
```

in the left join clauses and remove them from the where. Where is tested after the join and, as b will be all null, fails to find any matches.

Answer (score 0):

The "outerness" of the LEFT JOIN operation is negated by those two  predicates in the WHERE clause;

```
b.imgStatus = 0 and b.imgDeleted = 0
```

Those are effectively filtering out any rows that have NULL values, so the query is equivalent to an INNER join.

To make this an "outer" join, you can relocate those two predicates to the ON clause.  For example:

```
UPDATE items_mod a
  LEFT
  JOIN item_images b
    ON b.imgHandle = a.itemHandle
   AND b.imgStatus = 0 
   AND b.imgDeleted = 0
   SET a.itemPubStatus = 0
     , a.itemStatusSet = 1
     , a.itemAdminMessage = 'Test'
     , b.imgStatus = 1
     , b.imgPublished = 1 
 WHERE a.itemId = 2
   AND a.itemPubStatus = 2 
   AND a.itemPrePub = 1
```

Comment: `b.imgStatus = 0 AND b.imgDeleted = 0` but imgStatus and imgDeleted are both 1 now. So even this fails.